# How to configure Python syslog logging in local system?

Tags: python, logging, syslog

I have configured my Python logger to write logs to syslog using the SysLogHandler. In SysLogHandler configuration, when I set the address as '/dev/log', both application and access logs are written to var/log/syslog file.

Now, for testing on my local system instead of a remote log server, using the below netcat command I open up a UDP port where the logs should be written

```
                  nc -l -u 10003
```

I have also updated the address in SysLogHandler as ('localhost', 10003), but when I start my application, only the application logs are written and the access logs are not written.

I have two different loggers for application logs and access logs and I have set the same SysLogHandler configuration for both loggers. Is there some other configuration that needs to be done and I am missing it?

Here's the configuration json for the application and access loggers

```
    "cherrypy_access": {
        "level": "INFO",
        "class": "logging.handlers.SysLogHandler",
        "address": [
            "localhost",
            10003
        ],
        "facility": "auth",
        "formatter": "jsonacc"
    },
    "cherrypy_error": {
        "level": "INFO",
        "class": "logging.handlers.SysLogHandler",
        "address": [
            "localhost",
            10003
        ],
        "facility": "auth",
        "formatter": "jsonapp"
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean `application logs`? There are two loggers which are `access` and `error` but no `application`.

Comment: @Sraw Application log is the log file where application events such as exceptions and other code errors will be written. I have just named it as cherrypy_error.

Comment: How do you config your `syslog`? As `cherrypy_error` may send some logs with high levels such as `error`, `critical` but `cherrypy_access` may send some logs with low levels such as `info` which may be ignored. A recommended config for test purpose is `user.* /dev/console`.

Comment: @Sraw But even in case of different log levels, the logs are being written correctly when I set the address as "/dev/log". Only in case of localhost it is not writing.